# WIX MajorUpgrade and return code

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am writing an installer that also contains MSI package built using WIX. I check the return code after running msiexec and skip some error codes. For example user should't receive error when return code is 1638 (product has already installed)

But when the older version of product was installed the return code is 1603 (unknown error). I also want to skip this situation (user already get newer version)

Wix code is

```
<Upgrade Id="<GUID>">
    <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.product_version)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERFOUND" />
    <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.1.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.product_version)" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="SELFFOUND" />
</Upgrade>

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage=You have installed newer version $(var.product_name)." />
```

The question is how I can return another code than 1603 when SELFFOUND or NEWERFOUND properties are activated

Update: I didn't want to influence the return code, I want to get appropriate code instead the general fatal error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the return code of `msiexec.exe`. Its return codes [are documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the list is comprehensive. The service determines the exit code based on the status of installation.

**Update:** The only thing I can suggest is to use database functions directly:

1. [`MsiOpenPackage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370339(v=vs.85).aspx), and
2. [`MsiDoAction("FindRelatedProducts")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370090(v=vs.85).aspx) to run [`FindRelatedProducts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368600(v=vs.85).aspx) action which will evaluate `SELFFOUND` and `NEWERFOUND` properties by processing [Upgrade table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379(v=vs.85).aspx).
3. Then analyze the properties with [`MsiGetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134(v=vs.85).aspx).
4. Close the package with [`MsiCloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370067(v=vs.85).aspx).

Using the obtained values of `SELFFOUND` and `NEWERFOUND`, you can decide whether you need to install the product or not. If yes, you can run `msiexec.exe` or use [`MsiInstallProduct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370315(v=vs.85).aspx).

<sub>Disclamer: I have never tried to do anything like this, and I am not sure it will work. It should, yet it does not look easy.</sub>

Comment: If NEWERFOUND set I get 1603 instead of 1638 and I can't separate it from situation when really fatal error was happen

Comment: I guess there's no easy way to detect if newer version is installed: The thing is `DowngradeErrorMessage` causes the package to exit with error, the error is "newer version is installed".